# Need help making rectangles function like buttons (Android)

Tags: android, graphics, button

So I'm quite a noob using the Android SDK (I find it very confusing compared to straight java). This is my second day using it, teaching myself the whole way.

With that mentioned, I would like to know how to make a *Rect* act as a button.

Basically the user will tap on a certain Rectangle (that has been drawn on the screen, but how to draw it is a different question; I am **completely** lost with Canvas) and then I want to check the x/y coords of where they touched and see if was contained inside the rectangle, at which point the app will do something (like change the text in a textview somewhere on the UI).

I've been trying to do this for about an hour with no luck, if anyone could write up a small piece of source code on how to do this I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to assume you're using a SurfaceView to draw on. What you want should be pretty simple.

First, override the touch event in the surface view and store off the coordinates of the last touch:

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 x = event.getX();
 y = event.getY();
}
```

Then, check if your rect contains that coordinate:

```
Rect rect = new Rect() // Your rect

if (rect.contains(x, y) {
  // Contained in your rect
} else {
  // Not contained in your rect
}
```

I believe that's what your asking? Let me know if you're still confused.

Comment: To be completely honest I haven't even heard of surfaceview yet, so I wouldn't know how to use it to draw the rectangle. Could you perhaps make a very tiny program that draws the rectangle with Surface view, and then uses this touch event to make it change color? If it isn't too much to ask. The code that you posted is very similar to what I was trying (using .contains), except I was attempting to use an OnTouchListener which really confused me.

Comment: Oh okay well this is assuming you're creating your own SurfaceView. But you should be able to create your own onTouchListener as well and tie it to a view and listen for touch events in just the same way. But yeah. To do the drawing you're speaking of you might want to to look at the SurfaceView class and override its onDraw. That's where you have the canvas and can do things like canvas.drawRect(....);

Comment: For beginners, SurfaceView can be confusing. Look at the LunarLander API demo.

Comment: @Brayden I've spent about an hour reading through surfaceview and I have no idea how to make it work. Like Snailer said, I looked through the Lunarlander sample and the way they code is just so confusing. If it isnt too much to ask, could you write a small piece of code that draws a rectangle in the middle of the screen?

Comment: @Matt Hey sorry I was gone a few days. Do you still need a small piece of sample code for a rectangle?

Comment: @Brayden Yes please I would really appreciate it!